# Converting images from html to pdf using xhtml2pdf

Tags: python, django, pdf, xhtml2pdf, pisa

Recently I've used the tutorial from YT and other websites on how to convert HTML to PDF in Django. But it didn't work with the images.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.views import View
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

#Generates PDF
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None


data = {
    "company": "Dennnis Ivanov Company",
    "address": "123 Street name",
    "city": "Vancouver",
    "state": "WA",
    "zipcode": "98663",


    "phone": "555-555-2345",
    "email": "youremail@dennisivy.com",
    "website": "dennisivy.com",
    }

#Opens up page as PDF
class ViewPDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        pdf = render_to_pdf('html_to_pdf/pdf_template.html', data)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

I've looked for many StackOverflow posts as well as many docs, but as I'm just beginning in Django I don't understand how to solve this problem(I'm not the only one). I hope someone can modify this code and explain it *clearly* why it doesn't work.

I'm loading images in **pdf_template.html** using

```
<img src="{% static "html_to_pdf/images/img.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
```

Django 3.0.8

Python 3.6.3

Comment: I'm getting this in console *Need a valid file name!
'<img alt="My image" src="/static/html_to_pdf/images/img.jpg"/>*'